# How can I sort the installed Google Chrome extensions by date of last extension update?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, updates

How can I sort the installed Google Chrome extensions by  date of last extension update?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't sort installed Chrome extensions.

Comment: @Virtuality Thanks! I think you meant you're virtually sure we can't sort.

Comment: No probs :-)   Also, I see you work at Adobe Research!